# Перезагрузка оператора ввода: почему возвращаемый тип должен быть istream?

Tags: c++, ооп

Вот пример моей перезагрузки для класса BigInteger:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in, BigInteger& object)
{
    string input;
    in >> input;
    for (auto i = input.rbegin(); i != input.rend() ; i++)
    {
        object.digits.push_back(*i);
    }
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    BigInteger a;
    cin >> a;
}
```

То есть, я получаю свои числа на вход, ввожу их в свою переменную `a` и... возвращаю тип `istream`? а зачем? по идее на данном же можно завершить все это дело? почему я не могу сделать вот так:

```
void operator >>(istream& in, BigInteger& object)
    {
        string input;
        in >> input;
        for (auto i = input.rbegin(); i != input.rend() ; i++)
        {
            object.digits.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы можно было делать цепочку вызовов

```
int main()
{
    BigInteger a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
}
```

Выполняться будет так:

```
(cin >> a) >> b;
```

поэтому результат `(cin >> a)` должен возвращать `istream&`, чтобы на нём опять можно было вызвать оператор `>>`.

Операторы по сути те же самые функции и в данном случае цепочка превратится в следующее:

```
operator>>(operator>>(std::cin, a), b);
```

т.е. результат одного вызова функции `operator>>` подставляется как аргумент в другой `operator>>` на позицию, которая принимает `iostream`.

Пример цепочки для вызова member операторов:

```
int a, b;
cin.operator>>(a).operator>>(b);
```

Тут даже более явно видно, что у объекта `cin` вызывается функция `operator>>` с аргументом `a` и на результате опять вызывается `operator>>` с аргументом `b`. Если бы `operator>>` ничего не возвращал, то и вызвать `.operator>>(b)` не получилось, ведь объекта нет, на котором вызывать функцию.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно. Во-первых, вопрос с приоритетностью. Будет сначала `>> a` или `>> b` . Во-вторых, пусть `>> b` - первый. `>> b` идет ввод в переменную `b`, потом `>> a`. но почему возвращаемое значение `istream` позволяет делает цепочку вызовов? она их "объединяет" в единый `istream` или как?  распишите пожалуйста по-подробнее

Comment: @Learpcs немножко подредактировал

Comment: @Learpcs тут играет роль не столько приоритетность, сколько ассоциативность. Оператор `>>` [левоассоциативный](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), значит `a >> b >> c >> d` = `((a >> b) >> c) >> d`, а, например, присваивание, правоассоциативно `a = b = c = d` = `a = (b = (c = d))`